# Error in deploy my application Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am trying to deploy my code on the server.

I followed these steps:

1. clear cache
2. update vendor
3. add configuration of my remote database
4. change the value of access cache and log

But I'm getting this error:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException' with message 'You have requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.debug".' in /home/public_html/demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:106
> Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/demo/app/bootstrap.php.cache(1959): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->get('kernel.debug')
>              #1 /home/public_html/demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/FrameworkBundle.php(85): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->getParameter('kernel.debug')
>              #2 /home/public_html/demo/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2562): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle->build(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
>              #3 /home/public_html/demo/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2542): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->prepareContainer(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilde in /home/public_html/demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php on line 106
> ```

Comment: What version of Symfony are using?

Comment: the last version 2.4.4

Comment: Did you follow the documentation [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html] which says **Don't forget that deploying your application also involves updating any dependency (typically via Composer), migrating your database, clearing your cache and other potential things like pushing assets to a CDN (see Common Post-Deployment Tasks).** Furthermore, you may need to update the dependencies before deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, this error is being thrown in `bootstrap.php.cache`.

Symfony uses a bootstrap file to improve class loading performance, as documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/performance.html#use-bootstrap-files). However, you presumably copied this file over from your development environment, and it hasn't yet been regenerated for production.

You will need to regenerate this file either by running `composer install` or by running the build script directly: `php ./vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php`

Comment: I check the existence of the file bootstrap.php.cache there in the app and in the directly \ vendor \ Sensio \ distribution-bundle \ Sensio \ Bundle \ DistributionBundle \ Resources \ bin 
So all is well I want to know where to copy this file please help me